# The "you can't vote in this election" box is in the wrong place

Tags: bug, design, election, warning

When  I try to vote in the [Math election](https://math.stackexchange.com/election), I'm met with a dialog. But the dialog is at the bottom of the post:

[image]

On smaller displays (and on longer nomination posts), this can cause confusion if the box is offscreen when the vote button is pressed. Ideally, the "you-can't-vote" box should be attached to the button I'm not allowed to push, not the post I'm not allowed to push it on.